# Error when run "python eval.py" NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I run python eval.py to evaluate my model,and I'm getting the following error.

---

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection>python legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --checkpoint_dir=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/ --eval_dir=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/eval/ pipeline_config_path=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config

**WARNING**:tensorflow:From C:\Users\tky\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py:125: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
**Instructions for updating:**Use object_detection/model_main.py.


W1001 15:35:00.024803  2044 tf_logging.py:125] From C:\Users\tky\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py:125: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "legacy/eval.py", line 142, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\tky\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\tky\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 306, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "legacy/eval.py", line 103, in main
    tf.gfile.Copy(config, os.path.join(FLAGS.eval_dir, name), overwrite=True)
  File "C:\Users\tky\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 397, in copy
    compat.as_bytes(oldpath), compat.as_bytes(newpath), overwrite, status)
  File "C:\Users\tky\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 526, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open:  : \udc8ew\udc92\u80b3\udc82\ua0bd\udc83p\udc83X\udc82\udcaa\udc8c\udca9\udc82\x82\udca9\udc82\udce8\udc82\u0702\udcb9\udc82\udcf1\udc81B
; No such process
```

---

I tried various solutions,but the error wasn't solved.
I can't understand this error,please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your command with the correct arguments. You forgot the `--` at `pipeline_config_path`. Like:

```
python legacy/eval.py --logtostderr --checkpoint_dir=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/ --eval_dir=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/eval/ --pipeline_config_path=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```